# Maximization of a a PiecewiseExpand funcion

Tags: piecewise, maximum

I have the following 3 piecewise functions and their upper envelope.

```
 a = Piecewise[{{0.125 (0.1 + 0.1 (11.5 - 1 \[Beta])), 
        8 < \[Beta] < (11.4)}}]
 b = Piecewise[{{0.375 (0.1 + 0.1 (10.5 - 1 \[Beta])), 
        8 < \[Beta] < (10.4)}}]
 c = Piecewise[{{0.375 ((10.5 - 1 \[Beta])), (10.4) < \[Beta] < 12}}]

 functions={a,b,c}

 d = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[Max[functions]], 0 <= β <= 12]
```

[image]

I would like to obtain a list containing the number {2,3,1}. This is because the function number 2 in the variable `functions` (function b) is the first one that appears in the upper envelope. Then, the next one is the function number 3 in the variable `functions` (function c), the same for 1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Heres a very unelegant solution

```
Table[Ordering[functions, -1], {\[Beta], 8.1, 12, 0.1}] // DeleteDuplicates // Flatten
```

This pretty much evaluates the functions a bunch of points, finds the argmax, then drops all duplicates. (Although the output I get is `{2,1,3}`)

Comment: Thank you @user2757771, I think It is a good starting point. However, this way do not capture the fact that functions are Piecewise. Fore example, by running `Table[Ordering[functions, -1], {\[Beta], 8, 12, 0.1}]`  I obtain 3 as first number, this is not possible since function 3 is defined for `10.4 < \[Beta] < 12`

Comment: Yes, but piecewise functions default to 0 outside of their domain

Comment: @Andrea2810 The fact that a, b, c default to 0 is baked in to their definitions. You could define them to default to `-Infinity` and then discard the intervals where the maximum is `-Infinity`.